# Remove uninstalled feature when feature GUID not recognized

Tags: features

I have uninstalled a few features and am now getting an unexpected error when trying to navigating to the "Manage content and structure" page. The ULS logs show the following error:

"**The configuration database was queried for a non-existent object** with the id 191eae26-0fe6-41c6-86e9-8356bf08d7df. Most commonly, this is caused by removing an SPFeatureDefinition without writing upgrade code to remove references to the feature from each site."

How do I get rid of the error? I can't seem to identify which solution is causing the error. I have

1. Searched ULS logs for the GUID - can't find any references
2. ran `stsadm -enumsolutions` - no references found
3. run CodePlex Feature Admin - no feature with such GUID exists
4. ran `stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id 191eae26-0fe6-41c6-86e9-8356bf08d7df` - no such feature is installed.

Where do i go from here? Any suggestions would be really appreciated...

Comment: Try adding -force to the STSADM command

Comment: Adding the -force switch did the trick - the feature was uninstalled. 
The issue with the "Manage structure and content" page was due to something else though. there were "Detected use of SPRequest for previously closed SPWeb object. " errors getting logged. this turned out to be due to a particular list that wasn't automatically deleted on uninstalling a feature. 

This post (http://www.tylercranston.com/2011/11/cqwp-and-manage-content-and-structure.html ) helped me to find the erroring list - removing it got rid of all my issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding -force to the STSADM command