# How to fix the access issue with Timer JobDefinition Page - SP2010?

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs

I am unable to access the Timer Job Definition Page in Central Admin and getting error given below, if anyone can tell me how to fix this issue please,

```
The configuration database was queried for a non-existent object with the id a54efcb9-125d-497a-97f7-71cbc5d23d91. Most commonly, this is caused by removing an SPFeatureDefinition without writing upgrade code to remove references to the feature from each site.
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the
>   current state of the object.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationJob.get_UserProfileApplication()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationJob.get_DisplayName()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.JobDefinitionsDataSourceView.AddRow(SPJobDefinition
>   jd, DataTable table, DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.JobDefinitionsDataSourceView.AddService(SPService
>   service, DataTable table, DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.JobDefinitionsDataSourceView.AddFarm(SPFarm
>   farm, DataTable table, DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.TimerJobDataSourceView.FillDataTable(DataTable
>   table, DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DataTableDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   selectArguments)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AdministrationDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments)      at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

We have tried these options:

1. `Get-SPTimerJob | where {$_.name -match "User Profile*"} |%  { $_.Delete()}`
2. Restarted the services
3. Restarted the servers
4. Ran the Configuration Wizard
5. Ran the inplace upgrade commmand
6. We could not any corresponding entries in the objects Table in configuration database.
7. Cleared the Configuration Cache on the farm where the issue persist however User profile service is consumed from another farm.
8. Reprovisioned the Sync DB of UPA

Solutions are deployed properly and able to access all other pages than the "Review Timer Job Definition Page"...

Comment: Have you tried reprovisioning the User Profile Service entirely?

Comment: You have given us the stack trace of the Error Page displayed in the browser. How about sending me the ULS log file? I am sure it will display something more obvious?

Comment: Yes, have reprovisioned the Sync DB of UPA(consumed from another farm)

Comment: No, this is what available in the ULS too.

Comment: See my updated answer..

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to cleanup the Timer Jobs related to the User Profile Service. To do that you can executed the following PowerShell command.

```
Get-SPTimerJob | where {$_.name -match "User Profile Service*"} |  % { $_.Delete()}
```

[For More Information](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointadminprevious/thread/45cd502a-580d-49ab-85bb-e5ab10294474)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I would take to troubleshoot/fix your issue:

1. Clear the SharePoint configuration cache.
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx
2. Restart the user profile sync service via the Central Admin site.
3. Considering you have two farms (one farm is consuming the UPA off another farm as per your comment, please re-check all the steps to configure cross farm UPA services.. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/7eb602f9-fe3d-4117-a0b0-c36e27dc8df6/

and

http://www.sharepointninja.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=44

Ensure things like trusted farm and certificates etc are done properly.

4. Delete the UPA proxy on the consuming farm and follow the steps here. http://blog.schauweb.dk/post/2010/12/01/User-Profile-Service.aspx
   You will have to recreate the UPA proxy again.
5. Check if you can successfully view the 'Timer Job Definition' page in the 'publishing farm'.
6. Refer to this thread to assist you with 'The configuration database was queried for a non-existent object'. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/acc425aa-82bb-498e-8423-8cdffbc8b251/

and

[Remove uninstalled feature when feature GUID not recognized](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33645/remove-uninstalled-feature-when-feature-guid-not-recognized)

Comment: Followed the below steps

• Disassociated the UPA proxy from the proxy group.
• Deleted the UPA proxy on the consuming farm.
o Get-SPTimerJob | where {$_.name -match "User Profile Service*"} |  % { $_.Delete()}
• Recreated the UPA proxy and associated with the proxy group

The issue is still persist.